# String encode in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, encode

I am very new to Objective-C.

I want to get the encoded content for a NSString. In java I can do that as follows,

```
String str = "https://www.google.co.in/#q=ios+sqlite+crud+example";
String encodedParam = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
```

I am using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php to test the codes posted in stackoverflow. There is no solution yet. I know its trivial one. Struggling to find a way though.

tried with following function, and it says following error while compile,

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
       (CFStringRef)self,
       NULL,
       (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
       CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
```

}

Error,

```
    sh-4.3$ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -L/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lgnustep-base -lobjc *.m -o main                                                             
    main.m: In function 'main':                                                                                                                                                     
    main.m:7:14: error: 'urlEncodeUsingEncoding' undeclared (first use in this function)                                                                                            
     -(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {                                                                                                               
                  ^                                                                                                                                                                 
    main.m:7:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in                                                                             
    main.m:7:36: error: expected ';' before ':' token                                                                                                                               
     -(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
```

Edit as per the answers,

Suggested by Patrick, I used the code as follows,

```
NSString *storedURL = @"google.com/?search&q=this";
NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/",storedURL];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];

NSError *error = nil;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                 usedEncoding:&encoding 
                                                        error:&error];
NSLog (my_string);
```

Nothing printed in console... Is it my NSLog is right?

Suggested by lightwolf, my code is looks like below,

```
NSString *str = @"https://www.google.co.in/#q=ios+sqlite+crud+example";
NSString *encodedParam = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (encodedParam);
```

it prints the log, but value is same as the str..... not encoded... I want this str as

```
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F%23q%3Dios%2Bsqlite%2Bcrud%2Bexample
```

Comment: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding ` encodes only characters not compatible with URL encoding. "+" is an acceptable char (it means space) so it isn't encoded. BTW, for printing in console you should use `NSLog(@"%@", string)`

Comment: Why don't you use an `NSURL` object?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to encode a specific range of characters you chould use

```
NSString *str = @"https://www.google.co.in/#q=ios+sqlite+crud+example";
NSString *encodedParam = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
NSLog (@"%@", encodedParam);
```

Note the `invertedSet`; In that way, you are encoding all characters except the set specified (all alphanumeric ones)

The result is

```
https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogle%2Eco%2Ein%2F%23q%3Dios%2Bsqlite%2Bcrud%2Bexample
```

If you want to use a specific set of characters you should use

```
NSString *str = @"https://www.google.co.in/#q=ios+sqlite+crud+example";
NSCharacterSet* set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"!*'();@&=+$,?%#[]"];
NSString *encodedParam = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[set invertedSet]];
NSLog (@"%@", encodedParam);
```

In this case I intentionally missed **/** and **:** so the result is

```
https://www.google.co.in/%23q%3Dios%2Bsqlite%2Bcrud%2Bexample
```

Comment: Please edit your original answer instead of posting another one, unless both answers are two solutions for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want

```
NSString *str = @"<html><head><title>First</title></head><body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
NSString *encodedParam = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You have to encode only the params, not the entire URL of course

Comment: lightwolf, updated my question with your answer. pls take a look.